# Is it possible to import a .publishsettings file in Visual Studio 2015 community edition?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, publish-profiles

In Visual Studio 2015 (community edition) I can't see any way of importing a .publishsettings file to generate a .pubxml file without having to fill in all the Connection and Settings fields manually. From searching, I've determined that it should look like this (not sure what version this relates to):

[image]

But all I see in 2015 is this:

[image]

Does VS2015 Community Edition support importing? If so, how do you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In conclusion, 6 months later with 76 views, 2 upvotes, no replies, no further info available on the web on this topic, I have came to the conclusion that this is NOT possible in the community edition of 2015.